# Typescript: unexpected reserved word in PHPStorm

Tags: class, syntax-error, typescript, phpstorm

I´m trying to get a simple TypeScript file working in PHPStorm, but sadly there seem to be some misconfiguration by default as the class keyword is not recognized properly

**This is my TypeScript file:**

```
class Test{

}
```

**And this is the error I´m facing:**

[image]

**And this is my FieWatcher configuration of TypeScript**

[image]

How can I get TypeScript working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Program` options should not be `node.exe` (that would mean you are trying to typescript code as javascript). It needs to be `tsc` or `node tsc`(that means you want to run tsc to compile the file to javascript).

PS: this video might be helpful : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RWXGMug_Rmo&hd=1